# How do I reopen STDIN after closing it?

Tags: ruby, pipe

I want to "silence" STDIN for the duration of a child process I'm spawning, so that after waiting for it to finish, nothing the user typed into the keyboard is propagated to the parent process. (If I don't, all keystrokes arrive at the parent process in a batch after the child process terminates.)

I tried closing `$stdin`, then `reopen`ing it:

```
    stdin_orig = $stdin.dup
    $stdin.close
    @pid = fork do
      exec cmd
    end
    Process.wait @pid
    $stdin.reopen(stdin_orig)
```

But this throws:

```
in `reopen': closed stream (IOError)
```

How do I reopen standard in? Or is there a better way to ignore user input for the duration of a child process running?

Comment: Would [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system) be better?

Comment: Better in that it would achieve what you are trying to do, without the need of processes or manipulating stdin.

Comment: I don't think that's true. I see the same behavior when using `system` (actually, I used system in the very first implementation.) Sending INT to the system call will still, upon termination, proceed to emit all keystrokes entered while the command was running.

Comment: What do you mean by “emit”? What are you doing in the parent to read from stdin, and what is the child doing?

Comment: The parent process reads from stdin in a loop (it's a repl) If it receives a command, it executes it in a new process. For the duration of that process, the repl blocks, but upon terminating the call, all keystrokes received still exist in stdin so the repl tries to interpret them. I want to stop that.

Comment: The problem statement is actually here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426540/swallowing-user-input-while-running-a-sub-command I didn't get a satisfying response though, so I asked again in a more specific way; I didn't mean to double post it. Thanks!